# PHP hook (wpcf7_mail_sent) and JS event (wpcf7mailsent) don’t work together

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I’m trying to do something but it’s a little harder than expected, I need help.

I want to do 2 simple things with my form :
1 – writing datas in Database
2 – redirect on a thank you page

```
function createUser($contact_data) 
{
    var_dump($contact_data->posted_data);

    $phone = $_POST['your-phone'];
    $callname = $_POST['your-name'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

    addUserInDB($phone,$pwd,$callname); /* this part works fine */

    header('Location: https://www.google.com'); /* A - not working */

    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "https://google.com/"; /* B - not working */

            document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
            window.location.href = "https://google.com/"; /* C - not working */
            }, false );

            document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
            window.location.href = "https://google.com/"; /* D - not working */
            }, false );
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action("wpcf7_mail_sent", "createUser", 10, 1);
```

I tried four different methods, and now I don’t know what to do anymore…

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with this redirect?

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work either so I decided to use my own form without using contact form 7.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has a similar problem...

CF7 uses **ajax submission** for forms, and you are attempting to redirect the result of that ajax call, rather than the page the user is on.

You need some Javascript the page containing your form (e.g. in the footer) to handle it instead.

```
document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
  location.href = '/somewhere/';
});
```

n.b. you still need the PHP `wpcf7_mail_sent` action to call your `addUserInDB()` function